# close dropdown top menus by tapping screen

Tags: jquery

I made dropdown menus on top. But in order to close menus, i should click selected menu buttons. I am trying to close opened menus by tapping on anywhere screen instead of clicking selected button. 
How should I solve this problem? 
If you have some idea, please let me know. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best I can do without seeing your HTML is to point you in the right direction:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$('#selected_button').is(e.target)) {
         $('#menu').hide();
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: This is my one-stop solution, but I don't mind calling `e.stopPropagation()` before your `$("#menu").hide();` What's your thought on it.